# Jquery creating option elements in a for loop?

Tags: jquery

I have my `select` dropdown initially being created using `php` like so:

```
  <select id="cupcake-amt" name="amt">
         <?php for($i=0; $i<50; $i++) : ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
          <?php endfor; ?>
  </select>
```

How would I create a jquery function that rebuilds the options to a different amount. So instead of 50 options I would want it 12 later. What's the best approach?

Comment: Do you want to rebuilt the *already generated options*? Or do you want to skip the PHP and generate the options with JavaScript on page load? Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to rebuild your options upt 12 items in jQuery, you can do like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
      var options="";
      var numberOfItemsNeeded=12;
      for(var i=1;i<=numberOfItemsNeeded;i++)
      {
         options+="<option value='"+i+"'>"+i+"</option>";
      }       
      $("#cupcake-amt").html(options);        
   });
</script>
```

Working sample :  http://jsfiddle.net/yDh6x/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can just empty the select.. then use a variable to store the option elements and append it at the end.

```
$('#cupcake-amt').empty(); // <-- empty the select box - so it removes the 50
var x = '';  // <-- variable to store option string
for(i=0;i<theLengthYouWant;i++){  
   x += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>';  // <-- store how many options
}
$('#cupcake-amt').append(x);  // <-- append to the select
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/BSmKt/

Answer (score 0):

You can create JS function:

```
function generator(number, selectId) {
   var options = '';
   for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
     options += "<option value="+i+'>'+i+'</option>'
   }
   $('#'+selectId).html(options)
}
```

Then call the function, where `10` is number of options that should be generated and `selectId` is the ID of the target select element.

```
generator(10, 'target')
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cjG86/1/)